# FOSOAuthServerBundle requested a non-existent service

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, fosoauthserverbundle

I have some trouble integrate the FOSOAuthServerBundle...

When I try to access to oauth/v2/token or create a new client with a my controller I have this error :

> You have requested a non-existent service
>   \"fos_oauth_server.controller.token\

oauth/v2/auth redirects me to my fos user login form so I think this is OK..

My security.yml

> providers:
>           #my_fos_facebook_provider:
>               #id: my.facebook.user
>           fos_userbundle:
>               id: fos_user.user_manager
>
> ```
> firewalls:
>     api:
>         pattern: ^/api/.*
>         fos_oauth: true
>         stateless: true
>         anonymous: false
>
>
>     oauth_token:
>         pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/token
>         security:   false
>
>
>     # -> custom firewall for the admin area of the URL
>     admin:
>         pattern:      /admin(.*)
>         form_login:
>             provider:       fos_userbundle
>             login_path:     /admin/login
>             use_forward:    false
>             check_path:     /admin/login_check
>             failure_path:   null
>         logout:
>             path:           /admin/logout
>         anonymous:    true
>     # -> end custom configuration
>
>     # defaut login area for standard users
>     main:
>         pattern:      .*
>         form_login:
>             provider:       fos_userbundle
>             login_path:     fos_user_security_login
>             use_forward:    false
>             check_path:     fos_user_security_check
>             default_target_path: /
>             failure_path:   null
>         logout:       true
>         anonymous:    true
> ```

And here my config.yml..

```
fos_oauth_server:
    db_driver: orm       # Driver availables: orm, mongodb, or propel
    client_class:        Sportimimi\userBundle\Entity\Client
    access_token_class:  Sportimimi\userBundle\Entity\AccessToken
    refresh_token_class: Sportimimi\userBundle\Entity\RefreshToken
    auth_code_class:     Sportimimi\userBundle\Entity\AuthCode   
    service:
        user_provider: fos_user.user_manager
```

Comment: this should be fos_oauth_server.controller.token:tokenAction

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you have a idea why is it not?

Comment: nope. sorry. it needed myself a few hours to get oauth2 working. see this blog article series http://blog.tankist.de/blog/2013/07/18/oauth2-explained-part-3-using-oauth2-with-your-bare-hands/

Comment: I already read it, and spent lot of time on it.. I don't understand how make it work.. :(